# Number scrolling animation

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Scenario: 
I wanted to show an animation while increasing or decreasing a number. For ex. Let's say we have 12390 as a counter displayed on the label on the screen if counter increases say by 100; then I want to show upwards scrolling animation to reach the new counter (12490), similarly, I wanted to show downwards scrolling animation if the counter goes down.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: "I want" is not a question.  Please read [ask] before posting.

Comment: @Jason thank you for pointing out... I have updated the question.

Comment: like this? https://github.com/robinhood/ticker

Comment: @heinst yes like that will do, but I see that is for android I am looking for xamarin from solution or some similar thing to get a head start......

Comment: Cant find anything similar for xamarin, youll have to do either more digging or write it yourself natively as a renderer